# '91' Object Variable/With Block not set on ADODB Connection line

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to query a database to fill a listbox (as well as other various tasks). I get the following error when I run my code:

Error:

```
91 
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

My Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrDBPath As String
    Dim strSQL As String


strSQL = "SELECT [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], Sum([Heads A Issues].Downtime) AS SumOfDowntime1, IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew')) AS Crew " & _
        "FROM [Heads A] INNER JOIN [Heads A Issues] ON [Heads A].[HeadLineA ID] = [Heads A Issues].[HeadLineA ID]" & _
        " GROUP BY [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))" & _
        " HAVING ((([Heads A].[Date Entered])>=#" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 1).Value & "# And ([Heads A].[Date Entered])<=#" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 2).Value & "#) And (([Heads A Issues].Department)='" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 3).Value & "') And ((IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))) Like IIf('" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 4).Value & "'='all','*-Crew','" & _
        Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 4).Value & "'))) ORDER BY [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment;"

StrDBPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Daily Closing Report V997.accdb"

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _ 'THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
                         "Data Source=" & StrDBPath & ";" &_
                         "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                         "Persist Security Info=False;"

rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

CopyText (strSQL)

If (rst.RecordCount = 0) Then
    MsgBox "0 records found."
    Unload UserForm1
    Exit Sub
End If

If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rst.MoveFirst
End If
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    Do While rst.EOF = False
        .AddItem rst![Department,Heads A]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
     On Error Resume Next
     rst.Close
     cnn.Close
     Set rst = Nothing
     Set cnn = Nothing
     Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
     MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
     Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

I have narrowed down that the error is appearing on the line where I open my connection (marked above), but I'm not sure why it is acting up as it is. TIA!

Comment: Objects must be instantiated before you use them. Add the line [Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection] before cnn.Open

Comment: ...similar for your `rst` object

Comment: @DonJewett Same error. I've worked in VBA without that line before, is it necessary If I declare cnn as a ADODB.Connection object?

Comment: Okay it worked after @TimWilliams's suggestion, but error'd later down the road. That's another question in itself, though. Gosh, I've never had this much trouble coding in excel haha. Thanks guys!

Comment: @RyanWelsh - Yes, it is necessary. The examples you have probably seen do this in one line rather than two, like so: Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection

Comment: @DonJewett Post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early bind it as new.

```
Dim cnn As new ADODB.Connection
```

You can do as Don Jewett said and do it in two lines:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
```

That is late binding and in your case just an extra line of code. If you have code where your connection may never be made due to logic, it is good to do late binging near the opening of the connection so the binding doesn't happen until it is needed.  But since you are using your connection and recordset right away, you might as well early bind it.

Comment: As TimWilliams said in comments, I had to do the same with my recordset. This was the issue I was having, in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: That is not early/late binding - late binding would be `Dim cnn as Object: Set cnn = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")`   "Dim X As New Y" is *auto-instancing*